# Spring MVC maven Controller called twice

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am new to Spring mvc, maven and tomcat. I have written a controller for which I have defined a bean. Now when I type the url in broswer like: localhost:8080/hello.htm my controller is called and it is called again when I hit this URL.
Eg

```
<bean name="/hello.htm" class="com.paytm.controller.InventoryController">
    <property name="jdbcProductDao">
        <bean class="com.paytm.repository.JdbcProductDao">
            <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And in the controller

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setPrice(23.45);
    product.setDescription("Test Product");
    this.jdbcProductDao.saveProduct(product);
    ...
  }
```

As a result the product is saved twice in the DB. My query is why is the controller called when I type the URL(and not hit it)?

Comment: Try it again after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Which spring version are you using?

Comment: could you share the code of `jdbcProductDao.saveProduct` ?

Comment: @AbdullahWasi thanks! it worked. but still din't understand why was the method called on just typing the URL

Comment: @harshit : please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser caches your url when it sees 
the same url in the omnibox every now and then. Clear your cache and it will fix your issue. You can check your chrome `prerenders` by typing this in your chrome browser.

> chrome://net-internals/#prerender

For more details your can take a look at [this](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2014/04/30/unexpected-prerender-in-chrome/) source

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was something new for me. :)